# Charles Proxy - Response hangs when using Rewrite rule

Tags: charles-proxy

I am using the Rewrite tool in Charles to modify part of the Response body however the network request never completes.

The Request's "Status" value hangs and stays as "Receiving response body". It never changes to "Complete"

[image]

Here is the Rewrite rule logic I am using:

[image: Regex Rule log]

I am trying to replace the contents between 2 objects in the Response body. The starting object is called "termsAndConditions" and the end object is called "CampaignTermsAndConditions"

When I look at the Error logs in Charles, this is what I get

> - 2021/03/08 13:16:09 INFO     com.xk72.charles.tools.rewrite.RewriteFilter          POST https://www.my.fake.hostname/graphql?getApplicationWithCampaign Running: Body: termsAndConditions":[\s\S]*"CampaignTermsAndConditions -> termsAndConditions": [{ <rewrite_replacement_text> CampaignTermsAndConditions
> - 2021/03/08 13:16:09 Exception in thread "pool-726-thread-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 5
> - 2021/03/08 13:16:09     at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Unknown Source)
> - 2021/03/08 13:16:09     at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Unknown Source)
> - 2021/03/08 13:16:09     at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
> - 2021/03/08 13:16:09     at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Unknown Source)

I'm fairly familiar with Charles and I've used lots of Rewrite rules. I've never come across this issue before

Comment: Looks like the issue was caused by an unescaped '$' characters in the replacement string. I was using a very long replacement string and I didn't notice there were multiple '$' characters

Comment: You might try the Scripting from Proxyman app (Can do the same like Rewrite). It allows you to write If statement with Rebex in Javascript and replace the body from give JSON File that prevents your mistake. https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code#json